# Tree structure as a ItemsControl's ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to bind a simple tree structure to an ItemsControl's itemsSource in a Win 8 (formerly called) Metro app.
My structure implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and also notify, when any of it's children changed.

I tried to make a converter, which flatten my tree to an ObservableCollection, but after the binding created, it doesn't refresh.

I made the following test project to show what I would like:
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=970FFC53F4B7A598!146

The problem in this simple project, that if you press the Add button on the bottom app bar, it's create a new child in the hierarchy, but the ListView does not refresh.

What I miss, or how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fairly simple using a `DataTemplate`, e.g.

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeItemType}">
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"/>
    <StackPanel>
<DataTemplate>
```

Apply it implicitly via the `ItemsControl.Resources` (so it gets applied to the inner `ItemsControl` as well.

---

If you just want the leaves or take issue with items not being single units you could construct a [`CompositeCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx), other than the converter which creates an `ObservableCollection` which is never modified because only the view has a reference to it, you can wrap the original collection via [`CollectionContainers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectioncontainer.aspx), notifications will be preserved.

Comment: Could you please post a sample with the CompositeCollection and CollectionContainers solution?

Comment: Hmm. I suppose there are no CompositeCollection and CollectionContainer class in WinRT. My problem is, that I have a panel which made a custom layout of it's childrens. It's easily used with ItemsControl, but if I keep the hierarchical structure with using the solution above, i have no idea how to make the layout.

Comment: @adam_gav: That is unfortunate, you could of course implement your own. I think i have sufficiently explained the problem with the converter, you need to keep references to the original collections and react to their `CollectionChanged` events. The composite collection does not do much more than forward the events of its child collections.